# Can I use a free self signed SSL certificate for a secure Canvas URL?

Tags: facebook, ssl

Facebook require SSL certs for a secure Canvas URL.

I notice some organizations offer free, self-signed SSL certificates.  You can aslso find them  by using your search engine of choice.

Will these types of certificates be acceptable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may be able to use a Self Signed certificate but it will throw up browser warnings because your certificate isn't included in the ones that are trusted. To get a proper certificate you need to pay and get one through a Certificate Authority

According to [this forum post](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=106161) on the FB Developer Forums you should be able to:

> Facebook has not set up any requirements for the SSL certificate, but in the interest of your users not being showed an invalid signature dialog (It's looking pretty dangerous in firefox, while it's not dangerous at all having a self-signed cert) you should get a certificate for somewhere around 10$/Yr.

However the wording on the [Developer Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) suggests that you actually need to obtain a certificate. You could get the minimum required certificate for about $10/year and could save quite a few headaches

Comment: Thanks, I would still like to focus on the free nature of the SSL. So if not self signed, how about this one? http://www.startssl.com/?app=1
Also , where is a list of "trusted ssl"s as you say?

Comment: Where do you get certificates for USD 10 / year only??

Comment: Quite a few places do cheap certificates. For example, [Namecheap](http://www.namecheap.com/ssl-certificates/comodo/positivessl-certificate.aspx) supplies a Comodo PositiveSSL certificate for as low as $9 per year for a single domain

Comment: I have tested with a self signed cert, and it works fine without browser warning in Chrome but fails in Firefox.

Comment: that forum post in facebook no longer works. Anyone got a working link?

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately this problem is now solved with the free LetsEncrypt certificate. Hail the end of the SSL corporate maffia! :) https://letsencrypt.org/

Answer (score 2):

I have tested Start SSL certificates, and they work fine on all browsers in Windows XP, and even most mobile handsets. I did not find any advantage in low-end certs (

I tested on:

Internet Explorer 6
Internet Explorer 7
Internet Explorer 8
Internet Explorer 9
Firefox 6
Google Chrome
Safari
Android browser
Android Opera
Nokia Symbian opera
Iphone browser
Blackberry browser

Answer (score 0):

I have written a [proxy](https://github.com/manuks/proxy) which can be run in heroku.com and this will show your app in an ssl domain like https://your-app.herokuapp.com