# Self-signed certificate for servers hosting secure Facebook applications

Tags: facebook, certificate, ssl-certificate, self-signed, posting

We have a website, for which we have Self Signed Certificate available. We are posting our customized flash player to FB easily where secure browsing for FB is disabled by the end user. We need to post our flash player where secure browsing is enabled. 
We added meta tag with property="og:video:secure_url" with https:// swf content while posting to FB. 
But still the player is not loading, instead it's redirecting to another page upon clicking the image.

Do we need SSL here instead of a Self-Signed Certificate, or is there anything else we need to do?

Comment: Some useful advice at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319452/can-i-use-a-free-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-a-secure-canvas-url

Comment: Self-signed certificates are not usable outside of testing or within a closed network. All clients (and facebook becomes a client in this case) needs to be able to verify the certificates.

Comment: Thanks Sinisterfrog and Sean for the reply. :)