# Allowing specific files to run over https

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http, https

I have SSL set up on the server, but I hardly use it for anything, therefore I am simply redirecting all `https://` to `http://` via `.htaccess`. Recently I have created small app for my Facebook Fan Page, but run into couple of problems, since Facebook does not allow `http://` any longer.

Question:

How can I let one static HTML file to run with `https://` leaving the rest of the set up as it is?

What I currently use in my `.htaccess` is the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https [OR]
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: The real problem is that the file simply is not getting opened on facebook. IFrame is basically empty.

Comment: Any error? Is the SSL certificate self-signed? Are you working on Firefox? Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319452/can-i-use-a-free-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-a-secure-canvas-url) as well

Comment: No, not at all, the sertificate is not self-singed. I have tried, it works on firefox, but does not work on Chrome, Opera and other browsers.

Comment: I can send you link to my Facebook app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

In your first block with all the conditions, add a condition so that your app will be excluded. For instance:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !facebook-app\.html [OR]
```

For `your_app_name`, enter something specific that would only appear in the url for the App that you want to exclude from the rewrite. It does not matter if that name appears early or late in the url, just substitute it in the condition.

Comment: the url I pass on to facebook is http://www.mysite.net/facebook-app.html, so should I have it there in full?

Comment: Thanks for this worked on all browsers except Chrome. The iFrame is still a no show and certificate is complaining too, but I thing this has something to do with the content of my html file itself, so will need to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Glad to hear it's helping, Alex. If a browser is behaving differently, you can be sure that it has nothing to do with Apache. Many browsers maintain a cache of redirects, so if it was `301` redirecting before (permanent), your browser is redirecting your request automatically without even asking your server—faster that way. Best to clear the cache etc. Let me know if I can do something else. :)

Comment: I did, of course, but that stupid chrome is always giving me a huge amount of headaches :)

Comment: By the way, how to add folder to the rule that hold images that also have to pass through https://?

Comment: One easy way is to add it as an OR in the same Condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:facebook-app\.html|yourimagefolder) [OR]` Let me know if that works. :)

Comment: Nope, it did not work for me at all for some reason, but thanks for trying :)